# what does wait(null) do in this case and what is the output of the program?

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, wait

```
if (fork() == 0) {
    printf("[Child] I'm exiting\n");
}

else {
    wait(NULL);
    printf("[Parent] child exited\n");

}
```

`wait(NULL)` waits for **any** child to complete, and then it will execute everything after it. So in this case, what would be the output of the program?

We might  go into the parent first, and then we will have to wait for the child to complete, so its `[Child] ..... , [Parent] ....` printed.

We can also go into child, print its stuff, and then parent, in which case `wait(NULL)` will wait forever, since the `child process` is already completle. So in this case would an output be **just** `[Child].....`?

I ran `1000` times but it looks like the output its **always** child ... parent

Thanks

Comment: `waits for any child to complete` :: so,it *blocks* until wait()returns. And if it returns, you **know** that the child has terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the child hasn't exited, the parent will wait for it until it exits.

If the child has exited, the parent will obtain its status information and then continue executing. In this case, the function `wait()` will return immediately. [See this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html).

So this program will always print:

```
[Child] I'm exiting
[Parent] child exited
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the underlaying question you are actually asking is how [`fork`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) works.

When you do `fork()`, operating system duplicates the calling process (the parent). It creates a child, which is an exact duplicate of the parent (minus [some details](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)). The return value of the `fork()` function is `0` in child process and child's PID in parent process.

So, after your `fork`, child process will execute the code under the `if` clause, and the parent will execute the `else` clause. Keep in mind you now have 2 processes executing in parallel. The parent process, though, is blocked due to `wait(NULL)` until the child exits. When child (prints the message) and exits, parent continues to execute the code after `wait`, printing its message and exiting.

That's why you'll *always* see:

```
[Child] I'm exiting
[Parent] child exited
```